# IDLE no longer runs any script on pressing F5

Tags: python, python-idle

I cannot run any script by pressing F5 or selecting run from the menus in IDLE. It stopped working suddenly. No errors are coughed up. IDLE simply does nothing at all.

Tried reinstalling python to no effect.

Cannot run even the simplest script.

Thank you for any help or suggestions you have.

Running Python 2.6.5 on windows 7.

Could not resolve the problem with idle. I have switched to using pyDev in Aptana Studio 3.

Comment: You might want to try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), when removing it. It tends to grab things normally missed, such as some registry keys. You should also check *Options >> Configure IDLE... >> Keys* and check to make sure *Use a Built-in Key Set* is checked.

Comment: What platform are you running on (Windows, Linux, OS X, etc)? And what version of Python are you using?

Comment: When one starts IDLE from the Windows icon, there is no place to go for internal error messages from the tk graphics framework.  When IDLE has a problem, start it from a console (Command Prompt on Windows) with `python -m idlelib.idle` or with `import idlelib.idle` from an interactive `>>> ` prompt`.  Also, use the most recent release possible, as some crash problems have been fixed in the last few years.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a Dell laptop, and ran into this issue.  I found that if I pressed Function + F5, the program would run.

On my laptop keyboard, functions key items are in blue (main functions in white).  The Esc (escape) key has a blue lock with 'Fn' on it.  I pressed Esc + F5, and it unlocked my function keys.  I can now run a program in the editor by only pressing F5

Note: Running Python 3 - but I do not think this is an issue with Idle or Python - I think this is a keyboard issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your function keys are locked,I think so.
Function keys can be unlocked by  fn key + esc.
Then f5 will work without any issue.